# Batch file to execute SQL Server stored procedure from client to server

Tags: sql-server, windows, batch-file, stored-procedures, cmd

I have the following situation:

I need to execute a SQL Server stored procedure compiled on the server, passing some values. I'm creating a batch file to do this task. Something like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO Enter the initial date in YYYYMMDD format (eg. 20171201): 
SET /p pi_dte_ini=
ECHO Enter the final date in YYYYMMDD format (eg. 20171231):
SET /p pi_dte_end=
sqlcmd -Q "exec my_on_the_server_sp %pi_dte_ini%, %pi_dte_end%" -S server\instance
PAUSE
```

The problem is that I have to execute this .bat on a user's machine of our network. This machine don't have SQL Server installed, so it can't run sqlcmd. Any suggestions are welcome.

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to echo then run `set /p`. Instead add the echo text as part of the `set /p`
To execute `sqlcmd` remotely, use `wmic`

```
@Echo off
Set /p "pi_dte_ini=Set the initial date with YYYYMMDD format (eg: 20171201) and press Enter: "
Set /p "pi_dte_end=Set the final date with YYYYMMDD format (eg: 20171231) and press Enter: "
wmic /node:"servername" process call create ""cmd.exe /c sqlcmd -Q "exec my_on_the_server_sp %pi_dte_ini%, %pi_dte_end%" -S server\instance"
Pause
```

I cannot test this as I do not have sqlcmd, but you will probably need to adjust the double quotes in the `wmic` call.

Comment: `wmic` seems to be what I need, but I'm getting problem with quoting and escaping.

Comment: Because of the problems with quoting and escaping, I ended doing `wmic /node:my_server /user:my_user process call create "cmd.exe /c c:\temp\execute_sqlcmd.bat %pi_dte_ini% %pi_dte_end%"` and passed my `sqlcmd` call to that .bat on the server. Thanks for the help @Gerhard